# Permission denied error while creating files from a python script using mod_wsgi on apache

Tags: centos, python, httpd, mod-wsgi

I'm running a python script under mod_wsgi on apache. The script attempts to create some files under a directory. The path of that directory is defined by this variable named `tmpdir` in the script.

My script resides in `/var/www/webpy-app/scriptname.py`

When the value for `tmpdir` is : `/home/myname/test` then I get the following error in `ssl_error_log`: `[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/myname/test'`

However, when the value for tmpdir is: `/var/www/webpy-app/static` then everything works fine.

The permissions for both folders are:

```
drwxrwxrwx. 2 root    root       4096 Oct 12 19:08 static
drwxrwxrwx.  2 myname myname     4096 Oct 12 18:50 test
```

I start the httpd service as `sudo service httpd start`

**Question**

What can I do so that this pythong script running in apache using mod_wsgi can create files under `/home/myname/test`?

Answer (score 0):

Use mod_wsgi daemon mode and have the daemon process run as you.

The permissions issue is described in:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Access_Rights_Of_Apache_User

In short, by default your code runs as the Apache user and it will not have access to directories/files in home directories.